# Is the QCD Lagrangian without a $\theta$-term invariant under large gauge transformations?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, topology

In his book "Quantum field theory", Kerson Huang states that we need to add the term $$\frac{i\theta}{32\pi^2}G_{\mu\nu}^a \tilde{G}_{\mu\nu}^a$$ to the Lagrangian, to make it invariant under large gauge transformations. (Another reference is page 137 in "[The QCD Vacuum, Hadrons and Superdense Matter](https://books.google.de/books?id=rbcQMK6a6ekC&lpg=PA129&dq=%22pure%20gauge%22%20zero%20field%20strength%20vacuum%20not%20gauge%20invariant&hl=de&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by Edward Shuryak where he states that we add the $\theta$-term to "fix the value of $\theta$".)

This seems reasonable because large gauge transformations correspond to instantons, and these "generate" the $\theta$ term. When we have a field configuration and act on it with a large gauge transformation, we get into a field configuration with a different winding number plus the field picks up a phase $e^{i\theta}$.

I haven't seen this statement elsewhere and so far, no explicit calculation that shows this. In addition, I though that, by construction, our QCD Lagrangian is invariant under all $SU(3)$ gauge transformations. (See, for example, chapter 69 in [Srednicki's book](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf).)

Thus, as the title indicates, I'm interested in whether the QCD Lagrangian, without the $\theta$ term, is invariant under large gauge transformations?

For reference: A characteristic example of a large gauge transformation is

\begin{equation}
U^{\left(  1\right)  }\left(  \vec{x}\right)  =\exp\left(  \frac{i\pi
x^{a}\tau^{a}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+c^{2}}}\right)
\end{equation}